# HTML in Chart.js labels

Tags: javascript, axis-labels, chart.js

I'd like to put some images and/or links in my chart's labels. Here's the example code and jsFiddle:

```
var data = {
    labels: ['January', '<s>February</s>',
    '<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png">',
    '<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/">A Link</a>'],
    datasets: [{
        data: [65, 59, 90, 81]
    }]
}
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data);
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3UYJg/)

As you can see, the HTML is not parsed inside labels. Is there a way to have working images and/or links in the chart's labels?

Comment: Your fiddle does not work in Chrome: Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/Chart.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [Chart.js source code](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/src/Chart.Core.js#L1815) it appears that labels are rendered using the [`fillText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text) command. `fillText(text, x, y [, maxWidth])` only accepts a plain text string and so your HTML string will be render as plain text and all tags will be ignored.

One possible option would be to consider modifying the Chart.js code to use a `<foreignObject>` (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas) article on MDN and [this](http://robert.ocallahan.org/2011/11/drawing-dom-content-to-canvas.html) one which it's based on). For example:

```
ctx.translate(xPos,(isRotated) ? this.endPoint + 12 : this.endPoint + 8);
ctx.rotate(toRadians(this.xLabelRotation)*-1);

var data = "data:image/svg+xml," +
    "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
        "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
            "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" +
                label +
            "</div>" +
        "</foreignObject>" +
    "</svg>";

var img = new Image();
img.src = data;
img.onload = function() { ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); }

ctx.restore();
```

(Much of this code is a straight copy of the demo presented [here](http://robert.ocallahan.org/2011/11/drawing-dom-content-to-canvas.html) by Robert O'Callahan, simply modified to accept a label string and replace the existing Chart.js x label drawing code.)