# Add multiline labelString to yAxes Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have not found any questions on any site addressing this question, nor any documentation on how to answer it...

How do I make the y-axis in a chart made with the latest version of the Chart.js library accept a multi-line string as its labelString? I've tried

```
"Percent of users <br> that can come today"
```

as well as

```
"Percent of users \n that can come today"
```

and

```
"Percent of users &#13; that can come today".
```

Here is my code, I can add more of the code if necessary:

```
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    max: 100,
                    stepSize: 25,
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    labelString: "Percent of users \n that can come today",
                }
            }]
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631170/html-in-chart-js-labels

Comment: Could you solve this?I want to know how could you do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a separate grid to the side of the graph worked.